# Using webpack aliases in mocha tests

Tags: reactjs, npm, mocha.js, webpack, redux

I'm developing a web app at work in React/Redux/Webpack and am now starting to integrate testing with Mocha.

I followed [the instructions for writing tests in the Redux documentation](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html), but now I have run into an issue with my webpack aliases.

For example, take a look at the imports section of this test for one of my action creators:

```
import expect       from 'expect'                 // resolves without an issue
import * as actions from 'actions/app';           // can't resolve this alias
import * as types   from 'constants/actionTypes'; // can't resolve this alias

describe('Actions', () => {
  describe('app',() => {
    it('should create an action with a successful connection', () => {

      const host = '***************',
            port = ****,
            db = '******',
            user = '*********',
            pass = '******';

      const action = actions.createConnection(host, port, db, user, pass);

      const expectedAction = {
        type: types.CREATE_CONNECTION,
        status: 'success',
        payload: { host, port, database, username }
      };

      expect(action).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });
});
```

As the comments suggest, mocha isn't able to resolve my import statements when they are referencing aliased dependencies.

Because I'm still new to webpack, here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions : ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      actions: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'actions'),
      constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'constants'),
      /* more aliases */
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
};
```

Also, I'm using the command `npm test` to run mocha, here's the script I'm using in my `package.json`.

```
 {   
   "scripts": {
     "test": "mocha ./src/**/test/spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
   }
 }
```

So here's where I get stuck. **I need to include the aliases from webpack into mocha when it runs.**

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a way to do this ?

Comment: Yep, just posted my answer. YMMV

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Okay so I realized that everything I was aliasing was in the `src/` directory, so I simply needed to modify my `npm run test` script.

```
{   
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_PATH=./src mocha ./src/**/test/spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
  }
}
```

Probably won't work for everyone, but that solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: All of my stuff is also in `src`, but not sure how to implement your fix to my test script: `find ./src -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha --require babel-core/register`

Comment: This is a most excellent solution, especially compared to mocking and proxying require!!

Comment: this works great for me for a single test run, but I'm not able to get successfully watch files in an aliased directory, have you had any success watching?

Comment: I've started using `mocha-webpack` instead of this workaround. https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack

Answer (score 15):

You can also use a babel plugin I authored:
https://github.com/trayio/babel-plugin-webpack-alias
It will convert your aliased path to relative paths just by including a babel plugin to your `.babelrc`.

Comment: I clicked on your link and judging by the user information there and your user information here, it looks like you are the author of the plugin, so I edited accordingly, because it is against SO rules to mention software you created in an answer *without* being explicit that you authored it. (Doing so is considered spam, and carries severe penalties.) If somehow you are not the author, you can rollback my edit but make sure to clarify because otherwise, the next person who clicks the link risks making the same inference I did.

Comment: Also, this answer as it stands is borderline link-only. Adding information about how to install and use the plugin would fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not using this in production, but I am developing with it now.  It seems to do exactly as expected.  I'm a fan of alias, and I think using a babel-plugin to solve this problem is the way to go.  I haven't looked at the source or anything, but so far works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered the same problem, but with this plugin I solved it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-webpack-aliases

The execution command of your "mocha" is not reading the `webpack.config.js`, so it can not resolve the alias.
By setting this plugin, consider `webpack.config.js` when compiling with "babel-core/register". As a result, the alias will also be valid during testing.

```
npm i -D babel-plugin-webpack-aliases
```

and add this setting to `.babelrc`

```
{
    "plugins": [
        [ "babel-plugin-webpack-aliases", { "config": "./webpack.config.js" } ] 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I solved this problem. You should use 2 package: **[mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require)** and **[proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire)**.

Assuming you have a js file like this:

**app.js**

```
import action1 from 'actions/youractions';   

export function foo() { console.log(action1()) };
```

And your test code should write like this:

**app.test.js**

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import mockrequire from 'mock-require';

before(() => {
  // mock the alias path, point to the actual path
  mockrequire('actions/youractions', 'your/actual/action/path/from/your/test/file');
  // or mock with a function
  mockrequire('actions/youractions', {actionMethod: () => {...}));

let app;
beforeEach(() => {
  app = proxyquire('./app', {});
});

//test code
describe('xxx', () => {
  it('xxxx', () => {
    ...
  });
});
```

**files tree**

```
app.js
  |- test
    |- app.test.js
```

First mock the alias path by mock-require in before function, and mock your test object by proxyquire in beforeEach function.

Answer (score 4):

Danny's answer is great. But my situation is a little bit different.
I used webpack's `resolve.alias` to use all the files under `src` folder.

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '-': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  },
},
```

and use a special prefix for my own modules like this:

```
import App from '-/components/App';
```

To test code like this
I have to add a command `ln -sf src test/alias/-` before mocha test and use the `NODE_PATH=./test/alias` trick Danny camp up with. So the final script would be like this:

```
{   
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ln -sf src test/alias/-; NODE_PATH=./test/alias mocha ./src/**/test/spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"
  }
}
```

---

PS:

I used `-` because beautifal charactors like `@` or `~` are not safe enough. I found the answer for safe characters [here](https://superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you would have `--require babel-register` in your `mocha.opts`. You can use babel module resolver plugin https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver. This allows you to set alias in .babelrc, similar to your webpack alias:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
       "alias": {
         "actions": "./src/actions",
         "constants": "./src/constants"
       }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. It seems impossible to use webpack aliases in require.js or in node's require.

I ended up using [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) in the unit tests and just replacing the paths manually, like this:

```
var mock = require('mock-require');

mock('actions/app', '../../src/actions/app');
```

mock-require is a good tool, because most likely you'd like to mock most of your dependencies anyway instead of using the actual scripts from `src`.

Comment: It seems no work when I use mock-require, error still say can't find module 'actions/xxx'.

Answer (score 1):

To keep aliases in one place like `config/webpack.common.js`

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './../src/app')
    }
}
```

then install [babel-plugin-webpack-alias](https://github.com/trayio/babel-plugin-webpack-alias)

```
npm i babel-plugin-webpack-alias --save-dev
```

then in `.babelrc` put :

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["babel-plugin-webpack-alias", {
            "config": "./config/webpack.common.js" // path to your webpack config
        }]
    ]
}
```