# Using webpack aliases in AVA tests

Tags: javascript, webpack, alias, package.json, ava

I need to include the aliases from webpack into [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava) when it runs.

I used webpack's `resolve.alias` to access all the files under `src` folder:

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
  },
},
```

and then that `@` special prefix for my own modules like this:

**my-module.js**

```
import main from '@/view/main'
```

This is my AVA configuration:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "test-unit": "ava test/unit"
},
"ava": {
  "require": ["esm"]
},
```

Is possible to add something to package.json like in this mocha solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989394/12361834

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well you can do it with [link-module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-module-alias) npm package.

1. Add this to your **package.json**:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "link-module-alias",
     "preinstall": "command -v link-module-alias && link-module-alias clean || true"
     "test": "ava"
   },
   "_moduleAliases": {
     "@": "src"
   }
   ```
2. `npm i && npm test`

If you need further details you can download a working example [here](https://gitlab.com/gengns/ava-aliases).